# Handling custom server-side exceptions from server to GWT Client

Tags: java, gwt, restlet

In what way (and Restlet version) can a GWT application handle custom server-side exceptions and handle it from GWT client-side using the `ClientProxy` interface such that the app can check if:

```
if(exception instanceof CustomServerException){
 // Do UI stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restlet 2.3 introduces annotated exceptions that allow to hide the use of the class ResourceException and leverage transparently user-defined exceptions on the client side with client proxy.

For more details, you can have à look at this link: https://templth.wordpress.com/2015/02/27/exception-handling-with-restlet/

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Looks like in GWT it cannot identify (or serialized) the Exception thrown, on the onFailure method

Comment: For example I have if(caught instanceof PasswordException) then its not catching, whereas in the logs I can see the caught.getMessage is "unauthorized"

Comment: Indeed Restlet 2.3 introduced annotated exceptions but the user-defined exception isn't delivered to the GWT client, only a status code (see post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45505340/receive-custom-exceptions-from-restlet-framework-in-gwt-client)